# Response.Redirect Ampersand Encoding

Tags: asp.net, html

Failing to escape an "&" character in HTML markup creates an [entity](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/). It is often done inadvertently when linking URLs in a document, and W3C's [Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/check) will consider this an error.

I'm wondering, does ASP.NET's [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method expect ampersands to be escaped in its `url` parameter? From reading its MSDN description, I honestly can't tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the URL exactly as it should appear in the address bar in the web browser.  For example, if you're trying to redirect to http://example.com/?foo=bar&baz=quux, then pass that exact string as-is to Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 2):

try `UrlEncode`  The UrlEncode(String) method can be used to encode the entire URL, including query-string values. If characters such as blanks and punctuation are passed in an HTTP stream without encoding, they might be misinterpreted at the receiving end. URL encoding converts characters that are not allowed in a URL into character-entity equivalents; URL decoding reverses the encoding. For example, when the characters < and > are embedded in a block of text to be transmitted in a URL, they are encoded as %3c and %3e.  [URLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string url)
```

Comment: +1 for recommending good practice, but doesn't answer whether to pass to UrlEncode `&amp;` or `&`.